# Push notification is not being sent since its running on background, parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, parse-platform, push-notification

I have problem here that i don't really know how to solve.

I am using this code to send a push notification:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
  if(alertView == self.alert){

    if (buttonIndex == 1){


        // IF accepted was pressed, sent a notification to the requester
        NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [params setObject:self.senderChannel forKey:@"from"];

        [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendAccepted" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Success answer sent");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Failed to push");
            }

        }];
        .... rest of the code that opens another application on users Device
```

So the problem here is that the push notification (I THINK) is not finished running and sending on the background and the other application is started and the user is sent away from my application making the push notification not sent to the user.

I tried removing the code that opens another application and then a notification is being sent. All kind of help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your project settings,

> Section Capabilities

then make sure that you've switch **Background mode** to -> **ON** and in background mode make sure you've switch ***background fetch*** and ***remote notifications***, that's all.

Comment: Is it possible to call a web service in the background?, If it has to do with location services that is quite vital for the application?. If yes would this have a limited amount of time like 10 mins as i have read or would it have permission to do it for a longer time? Would apple reject that code? @ko100v.d